# Get Term ID by Description

Tags: taxonomy, description

I need to return the taxonomy term ID based on the terms description. Is this possible?

I know the description along with the term ID is held within the `wp_term_taxonomy` table. However I was wondering whether I could retrieve it through a function rather than having to use wpdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of ready-made functions that support this, but you can easily construct a [`WP_Term_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) to do this. The following code is untested but should work:

```
$args = [
    'description__like' => 'the description you\'re searching for',
    'taxonomy'          => 'category',//or other taxonomy
    'fields'            => 'ids',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
];
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
foreach ($term_query->terms as $term) {
    // ID is in $term->term_id
}
```

Comment: wp_term_query - great - never knew of it's existence. Thanks very much.

Comment: There are [various `_Query` classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=_query), always a good thing to check them out